# Magento 2 - Get all team members on a page

Tags: magento2, layout, template, development

I begin in Magento development and I try to do something but I don't know how to start.

I want to display on a "about us" company page all team members of a company, for example in WordPress we have to create a custom post type 'team members', but in Magento how to do that ?

I had the page 'About us' with a layout and a template.

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>

<!-- Get wrapper -->
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
    <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
    <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
</referenceContainer>

<!-- Content page -->
<referenceContainer name="content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="about_us_view" template="Magento_Theme::custom/about-us-content.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a new category from Admin side. Create a new CMS Page from Admin side (put your html content here). Then go back to the category and assign the newly created CMS page to the category from Admin.